# how to display blogs as a grid with wordpress

Tags: wordpress

I want the posts in the post to display like this:

[image]

I tried using the wp_query but I couldn't put it into the grid.

Can anyone help me please ?

Comment: Please send your website url i will give you the css then ?

Answer (score 0):

The grid is made using CSS once the HTML is output using wp_query. Therefore look into each post holder to have a max-width and floated left using the `float:left`

If you modify your answer and add your HTML output we can try to give you proper CSS for it.